# Excel, VB form with Text boxes. On button click. Create new row in worksheet with data from text boxes

Tags: vba, excel

Ive been looking around EVERYWHERE! And nothing works. ever.

I would like to be able to have a form that you fill in ( Lets say with two textboxes2 )
When you click the button it should then add a new row below all other populated rows and put the data of the text boxes into the cells of that row.

Nothing I do works :(

Does anyone have any ideas?
My form has:
Textbox1
Textbox2
Worksheet is called Sheet1 
( Ive left everything default while testing )

Any help would be epic..

Once I have this bit sorted, i can then modify to do what i want to achieve in the long run. but this basic " Add a row with some data" is just killing me.. It cant be that hard right?

Thanks
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could follow a logic similar to that : (After the click)

1. Find the last populated row
2. [Insert an empty row](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-rows-columns-or-cells-HP005200926.aspx) under it
3. Grab the data from the textboxes and copy them to their proper column

Does that help? If not, what part are you having trouble? I'll be happy to provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could get you started.  This assumes your first text box will fill in column A and second text box fills in column B.

```
    Sub InsertText()
        Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox2.Value
    End Sub
```

I don't think you need to add another row if you're just filling in below the last populated cell.  If so

```
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
```